# Tiny dent near the bottom bracket of a new hardtail - should I be concerned?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, bottom-bracket, trek, hardtail

I’ve just purchased a new Trek Roscoe 7 (aluminum hardtail mountain bike) recently and I’ve noticed this tiny little dent today. It is on the drive-side chainstay near the bottom bracket. [image: Direct view]

[image: Side view]

Should I be concerned about this dent? Is this a paint dent or a frame dent? Since it’s on a high-load area of the frame, will it affect the frame’s structural integrity and strength? What could be the cause of this dent and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Stop worrying. Go and ride your bike and put some real dents in it.

Without sanding it away it’s hard to tell if it’s a paint bubble or a small void in the forged section of the frame. Either way it’s of zero consequence for the structural integrity.

**EDIT**

It’s unlikely to be corrosion in a brand new frame.  You’d also need a local marine environment to have any real issues with that.

However if/when you get aluminium corrosion you can sand the paint and oxide away and leave the metal to open air.

You have a very strong/overbuilt production line frame. It should last you at least 10 years excluding crash damage.